# Why is this cursor giving an error?

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Insert_Monthly_Salary_Req]
     @xmlString  ntext
    ,@Message nvarchar(500) output
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare  @Emp_SL int,@Basic  decimal(6,2), @Grad_pay  decimal(6,2), @DA  decimal(6,2), @HRA  decimal(6,2), @MA  decimal(6,2), @Ptax  decimal(6,2), @Itax  decimal(6,2), @pf  decimal(6,2), @LIC  decimal(6,2), @Month_Of  datetime
    Declare @intDoc1 as int
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    print @xmlString
    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @intDoc1 OUTPUT, @xmlString
    declare Generate_Rq CURSOR FOR
    SELECT Emp_SL,Basic, Grad_pay, DA, HRA, MA, Ptax, Itax, pf, LIC,  Month_Of
    FROM OPENXML (@intDoc1,'/Salaray/TransactionSalary',1)
    WITH ( Emp_SL int,Basic  decimal(6,2), Grad_pay  decimal(6,2), DA  decimal(6,2), HRA  decimal(6,2), MA  decimal(6,2), Ptax  decimal(6,2), Itax  decimal(6,2), pf  decimal(6,2), LIC  decimal(6,2), Month_Of  datetime)

    OPEN Generate_Rq
    FETCH next FROM Generate_Rq
    INTO @Emp_SL,@Basic, @Grad_pay, @DA, @HRA, @MA, @Ptax, @Itax, @pf, @LIC,  @Month_Of
    print 'Line2'
    WHILE @@Fetch_Status<>-1
        BEGIN
            Print 'Line  ' +@Basic+ '    '+ @Grad_pay+ '    '+ @DA+ '    '+ @HRA+ '    '+ @MA+ '    '+ @Ptax+ '    '+ @Itax+ '    '+ @pf+ '    '+ @Month_Of+ '    '+ @LIC+ '    '+ @Emp_SL

            INSERT INTO [Monthly_Salary_Statement]([Basic], [Grad_pay], [DA], [HRA], [MA], [Ptax], [Itax], [pf], [Month_Of], [LIC], [Emp_SL])
            VALUES (@Emp_SL,@Basic, @Grad_pay, @DA, @HRA, @MA, @Ptax, @Itax, @pf, @LIC,  @Month_Of)
            if(@@ERROR<>0)
                BEGIN
                    rollback transaction
                    Set @Message='sp_Insert_PromtList: ' + @@Error 
                    close Generate_Rq
                    deallocate Generate_Rq
                    Return
                END
            FETCH next FROM Generate_Rq
            INTO @Emp_SL,@Basic, @Grad_pay, @DA, @HRA, @MA, @Ptax, @Itax, @pf, @LIC,  @Month_Of
        END
    CLOSE Generate_Rq
    DEALLOCATE Generate_Rq
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
    set  @Message='True'
END
```

---

The xml

```
<Salaray>
  <TransactionSalary EmpSL="2" Basic="9860" Grad_pay="4100.00" DA="6282.00" HRA="2094" MA="300.00" Ptax="150.00" pf="2000" Itax="0.00" LIC="0.00" Month_Of="14/Dec/2012" /> 
  <TransactionSalary EmpSL="1" Basic="12560" Grad_pay="4800.00" DA="7812.00" HRA="2604.00" MA="300" Ptax="150.00" pf="2000" Itax="0.00" LIC="0.00" Month_Of="14/Dec/2012" /> 
  <TransactionSalary EmpSL="4" Basic="11850" Grad_pay="4800.00" DA="7493.00" HRA="2498.00" MA="300" Ptax="150.00" pf="2000" Itax="0.00" LIC="0.00" Month_Of="14/Dec/2012" /> 
  </Salaray>',
```

It shows ..

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Procedure sp_Insert_Monthly_Salary_Req,
>   Line 26
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
>   Msg 16917, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_Insert_Monthly_Salary_Req, Line 27
>   Cursor is not open.
>   Msg 16917, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Insert_Monthly_Salary_Req, Line 47
>   Cursor is not open.

Comment: *Salaray* - really? Is that a new fish species? Also: avoid using teh `sp_` prefix for your stored procedure - it's reserved by Microsoft and causes performance degradation. And lastly: why on earth are you using a **cursor** for this???

Comment: What do you guess "Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric." might mean?

Comment: The error seems very clear: somewhere an `NVARCHAR` value cannot be converted to a `NUMERIC`. Have you looked through your code to identify where that could be happening?

Comment: i am unable to find out where this is happening? i also give the xml to . help me to solve this.

Comment: You have values `12560` for `@Basic` which do **not** fit into `decimal(6,2)` - that's a decimal with 6 digits total, 2 of which **after** the decimal point (and thus only **4 digits** before the decimal point - **not enough** to hold `12560`) ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an input XML, you can use this simple XQuery statement to "shred" the XML into relational rows and columns - just do a simple `INSERT INTO .....` and you're done. No messy cursor nor `OPENXML` stuff needed...

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Salaray>
  <TransactionSalary 
    EmpSL="2" Basic="9860" Grad_pay="4100.00" DA="6282.00" HRA="2094" MA="300.00" Ptax="150.00" pf="2000" 
    Itax="0.00" LIC="0.00" Month_Of="14/Dec/2012" /> 
  <TransactionSalary EmpSL="1" Basic="12560" Grad_pay="4800.00" DA="7812.00" HRA="2604.00" MA="300" Ptax="150.00" pf="2000" Itax="0.00" LIC="0.00" Month_Of="14/Dec/2012" /> 
  <TransactionSalary EmpSL="4" Basic="11850" Grad_pay="4800.00" DA="7493.00" HRA="2498.00" MA="300" Ptax="150.00" pf="2000" Itax="0.00" LIC="0.00" Month_Of="14/Dec/2012" /> 
  </Salaray>'

/* just add this INSERT INTO statement when you're confident the SELECT returns the right data! 
INSERT INTO [Monthly_Salary_Statement]([Emp_SL], [Basic], [Grad_pay], [DA], [HRA], [MA], [Ptax], [Itax], [pf],  [LIC], [Month_Of])
*/
 SELECT
    Emp_SL = XTbl.TSal.value('@EmpSL', 'int'),
    [Basic] = XTbl.TSal.value('@Basic', 'decimal(10,2)'),
    Grad_pay = XTbl.TSal.value('@Grad_pay', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    DA = XTbl.TSal.value('@DA', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    HRA = XTbl.TSal.value('@HRA', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    MA = XTbl.TSal.value('@MA', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    Ptax = XTbl.TSal.value('@Ptax', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    Itax = XTbl.TSal.value('@Itax', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    pf = XTbl.TSal.value('@pf', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    LIC = XTbl.TSal.value('@LIC', 'decimal(6,2)'),
    Month_Of = XTbl.TSal.value('@Month_Of', 'datetime')
  FROM
    @input.nodes('/Salaray/TransactionSalary') AS XTbl(TSal)
```

Also: mind you, you have values like `12560` for your `Basic` attribute - those will **NOT** fit into a `decimal(6,2)` - that's 6 digits total, 2 of which after the comma - which also means: only 4 digits *before* the comma - not enough to hold `12560`. I used `decimal(10,2)` instead - that works.

Gives me output of:

[image]